# How do I format new variables that I Create?

Tags: sas, format

I am trying to create a new variable in SAS.  I use if then logic to create a new character variable.  However, the variable is being truncated.  How do I format the new variable so that all the characters appear?

```
DATA Clinic;
set stat201.clinic;
rename age_at_consent=Age ldiastolic=dbp lsystolic=sbp ldobp=datebp;
if smoking="" then smoking="Missing";
if smokecat=0 then smokecat_1="Never Smoker";
if smokecat=1 then smokecat_1="Current Everyday Smoker";
if smokecat=2 then smokecat_1="Former Smoker";
if smokecat=9 then smokecat_1="Never Assessed";
attrib smokecat_1 format =$25.;
drop smokecat;
rename smokecat_1= smokecat;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

SAS will define the variable based on when it first appears.  Since the first appearance is in this assignment statement.

```
if smokecat=0 then smokecat_1="Never Smoker";
```

It will be defined as a character variable of length 12.

Just define the variable BEFORE using it.  You can use a `LENGTH` statement

```
length smokecat_1 $25;
```

or an `ATTRIB` statement to define a variable.

```
attrib smokecat_1 length=$25;
```

Attaching the `$25.` format does not change the length of the variable. 
 It just means that you want SAS to use 25 characters to display the values. But the variable will still only be 12 characters long.  There is no need to attach **any** format to the variable. Formats are instructions on how to display values and SAS already knows how to display character values.

Answer (score 0):

To complement Tom's answer above:

> SAS will define the variable *type and length* based on when it first appears.

I agree it is a good practice to define a variable before using it.